# How to mutate reference while moving ownership in recursive data struct?

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

I tried to implement `ConsList` data structure, where it came from functional paradigm language like Lisp or Haskell. Here some snippet for it:

```rust
use ConsList::*;
enum ConsList<T> {
    Empty,
    List(T, Box<ConsList<T>>),
}

impl<T> ConsList<T> {
    fn new() -> ConsList<T> {
        Empty
    }

    // I don't know whether to use & or not at self parameter
    fn insert_first(&mut self, value: T) -> &Self {
        // unkown implementation
    }
    
    fn head(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        // unkown implementation
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list_var: ConsList<i32> = ConsList::new(); // Initiate
    list_var.insert_first(2); // First insert
    list_var.insert_first(1); // Second insert
}
```

I wanted for `insert_first` function to behave like this:

1. Create new list with `value` at first position in new list tuple
2. Move value to the tail of new list
3. Replace owner variable (`list_var`) with new list

For example, when initiating, we have `Empty` value for `list_var` variable. Then at first insert, it will create new value `List(2, Empty)`, where `2` moved from `value`, and `Empty` moved from old list before mutation, and we mutate `self` variable to new list. In other word, we mutate `list_var` variable. For more in depth, here what I meant step by step at second insert:

1. Move `list_var` (`List(2, Empty)`) to parameter `self` in `insert_first` method
2. Move `1` to parameter `value` in `insert_first` method
3. Create new list with `value` and `self` moved to the new one, `List(3, List(2, Empty))`
4. Mutate `self` with the new list, so `list_var` variable will be the new list too

The problem here, we can only either:

- Transfer ownership without reference (we can't mutate `list_var`)
- Borrowing without being able to move (we can't move old list to new list)

As far as I know, we can't transfer ownership while being able to mutate with reference. There are some reason why this is useful. Method `head` will return first element of the list and mutate list to tail (I know mutation is not a thing in functional programming, but this will save storage and performance from copying new list). This method need to be able mutate `self`, move first element to return value, and move ownership of list tail to `self`.

I tried to use box for indirection, but still I can't move `self.list` because it's behind a reference

```rust
enum ConsListElem<T> {
    Empty,
    List(T, Box<ConsListElem<T>>),
}

pub struct ConstList<T> {
    list: Box<ConsListElem<T>>,
}

impl<T> ConstList<T> {
    pub fn cons(&mut self, value: T) -> &ConstList<T> {
        self.list = Box::new(ConsListElem::List(value, self.list));
        self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [std::mem::replace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to modify something behind mutable reference and return the old value. So inside `insert_first` you can firstly replace `self` with `Empty` variant, and then create new `List` and assign it to `self`.

```rust
enum ConsList<T> {
    Empty,
    List(T, Box<ConsList<T>>),
}

impl<T> ConsList<T> {
    fn new() -> ConsList<T> {
        Self::Empty
    }

    fn insert_first(&mut self, value: T) -> &mut Self {
        match self {
            Self::Empty => {
                *self = Self::List(value, Box::new(Self::new()))
            }
            Self::List(_, _) => {
                let old = std::mem::replace(self, Self::new());
                *self = Self::List(value, Box::new(old));
            }
        }
        self
    }
    
    fn head(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        match self {
            Self::Empty => None,
            Self::List(head, _) => Some(head),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list_var: ConsList<i32> = ConsList::new(); // Initiate
    assert_eq!(list_var.head(), None);
    list_var.insert_first(2); // First insert
    assert_eq!(list_var.head(), Some(&2));
    list_var.insert_first(1); // Second insert
    assert_eq!(list_var.head(), Some(&1));
}
```